# Show $g:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f:[0, 1]×[0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and assume that for all $x \in [0, 1]$ there is a unique $y_x$ such that $f(x,y_x)$ = $\max\{f(x,y):y∈[0, 1]\}$. If $g(x) =y_x$, then $g:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is continuous.

Is this true? I believe compactness would play a role.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi(x) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} f(x,t)$, it is not hard to show that $\psi$ is continuous.

Suppose $x_n \to x$, then $\psi(x_n) \to \psi(x)$. Let $g_n$ be such that $\psi(x_n) = f(x_n,g_n)$.

Any subsequence of $g_n$ has an accumulation point $g$ and we must have $\psi(x) = f(x,g)$
by continuity.

By uniqueness, we see that, in fact, $g_n \to g$.

This shows that $g(x_n) \to g(x)$.

Comment: How is your $\psi(x)$ defined? Is it $\psi(x) = \sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]} (x - t)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for $x \in [0,1]$? @copper.hat

Comment: @user439126: Oops, I had a missing $f$ in the definition (my f key is flakey).

Comment: That's a really inconvenient key to be flakey  around these parts lol. Thanks. @copper.hat

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I started writing this before I noticed the answer by *copper.hat*. Both answer's are saying pretty much the same thing.

**Assumption**: $f:X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is continuous and $X, Y$ are compact.

Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence which converges to some $\hat{x}$ and
$y_{n}\equiv g(x_{n})$. Let $y_{n_{k}}$ be a subsequence which converges
to some $\hat{y}$. Then,
$$
\max_{y}f(\hat{x},y)=\max_{y}\lim_{k}f(x_{n_{k}},y)=\lim_{k}\max_{y}f(x_{n_{k}},y)=\lim_{k}f(x_{n_{k}},y_{n_{k}})=f(\hat{x},\hat{y}).
$$
In the above, the first and last equalities use the continuity
of $f$. The second equality uses the fact that the function defined
by $h(x)\equiv\max_{y}f(x,y)$ is continuous.

We have established that $\hat{y}$ is a maximizer of $y\mapsto f(\hat{x},y)$.
But since maximizers are unique, it follows that $g(\hat{x})=\hat{y}$.
Using the fact that [if every convergent subsequence of a bounded sequence converges to the same point then the original sequence converges to that point also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776899/if-every-convergent-subsequence-converges-to-a-then-so-does-the-original-boun), we have $g(x_{n})=y_{n}\rightarrow\hat{y}=g(\hat{x})$,
and the claim is proved.

Comment: How were you able to interchange the $\lim$ and $\max$?@parsiad?

Comment: Since $f$ is defined on a compact set, it is uniformly continuous.
Therefore, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x,y)-f(x^{\prime},y)|<\epsilon$ and hence
$$
|h(x) - h(x^\prime)|
\leq
\max_{y}|f(x,y)-f(x^{\prime},y)|<\epsilon
$$
whenever $|x-x^{\prime}|<\delta$, establishing the continuity of $h$.
Then, we use the fact that [continuous functions and limits can be interchanged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776182/what-is-the-most-general-setting-in-which-limits-commute-with-continuous-functio).