# Convergence of power matrix $ (I-\nu P)^m \to (I-P), \ for \ m \to \infty, $ with $0 < \nu < 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, projective-space

Suppose $P$ is a $n \times n$ projection matrix with two eigenvalues equal to one. Is it true that and how can I show that
$$
(I-\nu P)^m \to (I-P), \quad for \ m \to \infty,
$$
with $0 < \nu < 1$.

My attempt:
Let $P=ODO^T$ be an eigendecomposition with $OO^T=I$ and $D=diag(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ where $d_1=d_2=1$ and $d_k=0 \ (k=3, \dots, n)$.
Then
$$
(I-\nu P)^m = O(I-\nu D)^mO^T=Odiag((1-\nu d_k)^m)O^T
$$
For $k=1, 2$, $(1-\nu d_k)^m \to 0$ and for $k=3, \dots, n$, $(1-\nu d_k)^m = 1$. 
Since those are the eigenvalues of the orthogonal complement $I-P$, the claim follows.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. As you can tell, the claim is independent of how many of the eigenvalues are one and how many are zero (see also my answer).

Comment: For future reference, you can use `\operatorname{diag}(x)` for $\operatorname{diag}(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that projection matrices are idempotent (i.e.,
$P^2=P$) and the binomial theorem,
$$
\left(I-vP\right)^{m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\left(-vP\right)^{k}=I+P\sum_{k=1}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\left(-v\right)^{k}=I-P+P\left(1-v\right)^{m}\rightarrow I-P.
$$

Comment: One follow-up, does this also imply: $||(I-\nu P)^m f||_2^2 \to ||(I-P)f||_2^2$ where $||.||_2^2$ is the Euclidean norm and $f$ is some real-valued vector?

Comment: If $g$ is a continuous function and $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $g(x_n) \rightarrow x$ (this fact is also known as [limits and continuous functions commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776182/what-is-the-most-general-setting-in-which-limits-commute-with-continuous-functio)). In your case, $g(x) = \Vert x f \Vert_2^2$ and $x_n = (I - v P)^n$. In short, yes, **your claim is true**.

Comment: For future reference, you can use `\Vert` for $\Vert$ and `\cdot` for the $\cdot$ symbols.