# Sequences and continuous function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, continuity

I would like to prove the following:

**Lemma**.
Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous function. Let $x_n \in X$ such that $\lim_n x_n = a \in X$ and $\Vert f(x_n)\Vert < c$ for all $x_n \in X$.
Then $\Vert f(a)\Vert \leq c$.

#### My attempt

We know that $\lim_n x_n = a$.
Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_n f(x_n) = f(a)$.
Let $\epsilon >0$.
Then, there exists $n_0$ such that $\Vert f(x_n) - f(a)\Vert < \epsilon$ whenever $n > n_0$.
Then, $$\Vert f(a)\Vert - \Vert f(x_n)\Vert \leq \Vert f(x_n) - f(a)\Vert < \epsilon.$$
Using $\Vert f(x_n)\Vert < c$, it follows that $\Vert f(a)\Vert < \epsilon + c$.
Therefore, taking $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ yields the desired result.

Is that correct?

Comment: The strict inequality will not survive the limiting procedure. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, $n=1$ and $f(x)=x$. Then take $x_n =1-1/n$, $a=1$ and $c=1$ to see that it will not be true.

Comment: can you give me a hint?

Comment: What do you mean? It is not true in this form and I gave you a counterexample. It becomes true if you write $\Vert f(a) \Vert \leq c$. Then your proof works.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, but as Severin said you can't take strict inequality at the end, just less than or equal to

Comment: oh, I just made a typo mistake, now is it correct?

Comment: Typo still exists at the top of the post. You also don't mention that $f$ is continuous outside of the title. You can edit your post to fix these issues.

Comment: ok, thank you, it's done.

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to resort to proving it from first principles. Left you a short proof below.

Comment: @user638057: Some $\LaTeX$ tips. Don't use `||`, use `\Vert`. Also, don't use `\displaystyle` (unless you absolutely have to) in inline math. The result is hard to read as it messes with the line spacing. I edited your post; you can look at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g\equiv\Vert f\Vert$ and note that $g$ is [continuous since it is
the composition of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527855/real-analysis-continuity-of-a-composition-function).
Take limits on both sides of $g(x_{n})\leq c$ to get $\lim_{n}g(x_{n})\leq c$.
Since [continuous functions and limits commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776182/what-is-the-most-general-setting-in-which-limits-commute-with-continuous-functio), it follows that $\Vert f(a)\Vert=g(a)=g(\lim_{n}x_{n})=\lim_{n}g(x_{n})\leq c$, as desired.